# Issue tracker that supports geo location

Tags: defect-tracking

Is there a free issue tracker software that

- permits to attach a location to an issue (preferably by marking the location on a map),
- permits to filter issues by location (preferably by displaying all issues on a selected part of a map), and
- permits to flexibly define further fields describing an issue and filter issues by these fields?

Standard issue trackers like Redmine or Bugzilla appear not to provide support for tagging issues with geo locations. Furthermore, while [openstreetbugs](http://openstreetbugs.schokokeks.org/) (a tool for tracking issues with the geo data of the Openstreetmap project) is centered around the idea of marking issues on a map, it does not permit to freely define the structure of an issue.

Comment: I do not understand how this relates to software testing, aside from the fact that testers tend to use an issue tracking system with different features than what you described.  Have you tried the GIS stackexchange site?

Comment: Just curious - what added benefit would a location provide for issue tracking?

Comment: why can't you just write your location in the bug?

Answer (score 2):

I know that Bugzilla can add whatever custom fields you feel like. Perhaps you could have it auto-populate?